# unable to install lmc_1.2_32_i386 in ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04

I recently shifted to ubuntu14.04 and when i try to install lan messenger, it gives an error of bad quality image. I downloaded it from official site of lan messenger for ubuntu.

These are errors:-

```
Lintian check results for /home/rahul/Downloads/lmc_1.2.32_i386(1).deb:
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset), LC_ALL = (unset), LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1" are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
E: lmc: control-file-has-bad-permissions postinst 0775 != 0755 E: lmc: control-file-has-bad-permissions postrm 0775 != 0755
E: lmc: control-file-has-bad-permissions prerm 0775 != 0755 –
```

Comment: please show the error to..

Comment: Lintian check results for /home/rahul/Downloads/lmc_1.2.32_i386(1).deb:
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
E: lmc: control-file-has-bad-permissions postinst 0775 != 0755
E: lmc: control-file-has-bad-permissions postrm 0775 != 0755
E: lmc: control-file-has-bad-permissions prerm 0775 != 0755

Comment: update in question.. it will understandable easily...

Answer (score 0):

try the following command,

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 cy_GB.UTF-8
```

Comment: Generation Complete. Should i try to install it again/

Comment: @RahulSehdev yes you try..

Comment: nothing happened. do you know any other way to install lan messenger ( lmc_1.2.32_i386) ?

Comment: @RahulSehdev are you getting the same error ? else update it...

Comment: Yes , I am trying to installing lmc_1.2.32_i386.deb file through Ubuntu software center. When i click install button it gives error although it having a option of IGNORE AND INSTALL . When i click this installation completed within 2 seconds and we get back to same position of install.

Comment: @RahulSehdev did you check is it installed or not ?

Comment: It is installed. I searched it in computer but when i click on it , nothing poped up